# how to add collapse view for search widget in android activity?

Tags: android, android-edittext, searchview

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE) {

            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_bar_l, menu);
        } else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL) {

            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_bar, menu);
        } else if ((getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL) {

            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_bar, menu);
        } else {

            inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_bar, menu);
        }
        View v = (View) menu.findItem(R.id.my_action).getActionView();


        /** Get the edit text from the action view */
        txtSearch = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.myActionEditText);

//      edit_searchtext = txtSearch.getText().toString();
        /** Setting an action listener */

        ImageView Search = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.search);
        Search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                search_value = txtSearch.getText().toString();
                if (txtSearch.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            "Please enter search values", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                } else {

                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                            Display.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Action_search", txtSearch.getText()
                            .toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                    txtSearch.setText("");
                }
            }

        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

i have created a cutomized searchview in menu item with collapse view action but the search edit text does not collapse on entering the search value and clicking the search button.

my menubar activity is:

```
<item android:id="@+id/my_action"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="My Action"
          android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
          android:actionLayout="@layout/my_action" />
```

how can i collapse the edittext once i enter the search value and click on imageview search..
Please help